# Emulate MySQL command line arguments/option files for host/user/password with Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I want to write a maintenance script in Python that connects to a MySQL database and does something.

Standard MySQL utilities (`mysql`, `mysqldump`, etc.) have a common configuration structure in that each reads `/etc/my.cnf`, `~/.my.cnf` or the file referred to by `--defaults-file` or none if `--no-defaults` is given, adds the contents of `--defaults-extra-file` to that, lets those be overridden by the `--host`, `--user`, `--port` and `--password` options, prompts for a password if necessary, etc.  (I hope "etc." conveys my vague understanding of all the cogs that can be turned.)

It would be very nice to have the *exact* same mechanism in my script so that users are not surprised, but feel familiar with the environment.  I have looked at [MySQL-Python](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/), [MySQL Connector/Python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/) and [oursql](https://pythonhosted.org/oursql/), but none of these seem to offer this functionality out of the box.  How can I emulate it in Python?

Comment: I assume you've already checked the 3 different MySQL Python libraries to make sure none of them do it out of the box, so… If `mysql`, `mysqldump`, etc. have a library that they use to do this, at very worst you should be able to use `ctypes` to call the same library. If not, presumably you have to port the code from C to Python (hey, at least it's open source so you can do that), extract the C code into a library that you can `ctypes`, or write equivalent Python code from scratch.

Comment: But meanwhile, is it really true that it looks at `/etc/my.cnf` and `~/.my.cnf`, rather than at some config directories that are baked in at configure time? I'd be really surprised if something I installed to `/usr/local/bin` instead of `/usr/bin` wanted to store config files in `/etc` instead of `/usr/local/etc`, for example.

Comment: I had indeed looked at the libraries and just edited the question to reflect that.  `/etc/my.cnf` & Co. are a placeholder for the actual compilation options, but I didn't want to make the question unreadable :-).  If porting would be necessary and complicated, I would probably consider either surprising the users with yet-another-way-to-specify-MySQL-database-connections or writing the maintenance script in C++ as the MySQL client programs seem to be written in it.

Comment: You don't have to write the whole script in C++; just write the command-line/config/etc. parsing code in C++, build it as a shared lib, and write everything else in Python, accessing the shared lib via `ctypes`. (Or use Cython, or any of the other ways of mixing C++ and Python, whatever you're most familiar with.)

Comment: The maintenance script in C++ would probably be a lot shorter than the glue needed to bind Python and C++ together, especially with regard to parsing command line arguments :-).